# Помогите пожалуйста написать программу

Tags: c

Помогите пожалуйста написать программу которая вводит 4 строки, представляющие целые значения, и превращает их в целые числа, добавляет их и выводит сумму этих значений.У меня практически нет идей как это сделать, надуюсь вы сможете помочь

```
int main()
{
    char str1, str2, str3, str4;

    printf("please input 1 line:");
    scanf("%s", &str1);
    printf("please input 2 line:");
    scanf("%s", &str2);
    printf("please input 3 line:");
    scanf("%s", &str3);
    printf("please input 4 line:");
    scanf("%s", &str4);

    //for(char* str1; str1++;){
    //if (!(isdigit(*str1))) return 0; // не число
    //}
    //return 1;
}
```

Comment: А сразу вводить как числа нельзя?

Comment: Думаю можно, я долго думал как это сделать

Comment: @Nedzyko, *`"я долго думал как это сделать"`* -- наверное пора **вимательно прочесть** любой учебник по Си, первый раз, не отрываясь, от начала до конца (все буквы), а дальше ... может и спрашивать подобное уже не придется

Answer (score 2):

```
int main()
{
    int sum = 0, x;
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        printf("please input %d number: ",i+1);
        scanf("%d",&x);
        sum += x;
    }
    printf("Sum = %d\n",sum);
}
```

Можно (нужно :)) добавить код проверки корректности ввода, но если вводить без ошибок - сработает и так...